# cross table update can't work

Tags: mysql

I tried many code (some from stackoverflow), none of them can work.

Here is the structure of my mysql database:

```
table hesk_tickets : id, name, email

table hesk_callers : empnum, email, dept
```

the `name` column in `hesk_tickets` references the employee number, as does the `empnum` in `hesk_callers`

At beginning there is no other employee info in `hesk_tickets` but `name`. I want to add more employee info into it to make it easy to callback.

Then I import an xls file containing employee info into a new table named `hesk_calles`. I want to update `hesk_tickets` columns like email on lines that match the employee number in `hesk_callers`.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE hesk_tickets t1, hesk_callers t2
SET t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t1.name = t2.empnum;
```

also tried

```
UPDATE hesk_tickets ht
JOIN hesk_callers hc ON ht.name = hc.empnum
SET ht.email = hc.email
```

0 row(s) affected.

there are 6000 records in hesk_tickets and 1000 records in hesk_callers.

any solution will be appreciated,thx.

Comment: Can you show some sample data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?  Based on the information you have given, the `UPDATE` statement you tried *should* work.

Comment: Why does a column called *Name* contain an Employee *Number*?

Answer (score 1):

Try executing

`select count(*) from hesk_tickets ht join hesk_callers hc on ht.name = hc.empum`

to verify you actually have some matching data to update. You'll probably find that query returns zero. If that returns a number greater than zero, then it means that your UPDATE query is affecting zero rows because the email addresses already match (and therefore don't need updating)

Comment: Ok, now do this query `select count(*) from hesk_tickets ht join hesk_callers hc on ht.name = hc.empum where ht.email = hc.email` - this is showing the number of records that already have the same email address

Comment: thanks matthewh, actually the second codes work! like you said the email address already match so it said zero rows affect. I tried other fields like address and department and carefully check it, some records indeed been updated, thanks again.